# If $x ,y,z$ are three natural numbers in AP such that $x+ y+ z= 30$, then how many ordered triplets $(x,y,z)$ are possible?

Tags: combinatorics

I figured out that $x = a , y = a+d , z= a+2d$ .
Then  $x+ y+z = 30
\implies a + d = 10$
So no of natural solutions is $9$
And reversing the order of the triplet the total is $18$. But the correct answer is given as $19$ . Please explain where I went wrong.

Comment: you forgot the case when d=0, so there will be one extra ordered pair $(x,y,z)=(10,10,10)$

Comment: Ok . But can you verify whether the rest of my solution is correct

Comment: Does $x,y,z$ is natural numbers mean that $d$ must be a natural number? I mean, even when $d=-10$, we have $(x,y,z)=(20,10,0)$.

Comment: @HawShief Those solutions are counted when the OP *"reverses the order"*, right?

Comment: @Haw, your triplet is (20,10,0), but 0 is NOT a natural number!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I will now clear any confusion. First, let's talk about what the question is asking.
$x, y, z$ are three natural numbers. From this, we deduce that $x, y, z$ are necessarily positive(>0). And we've been given than $x, y, z$ form an arithmetic progression(A.P.). Note that an A.P. need not be increasing. Finally, we have $x+y+z=30$. 
We've been asked to find the number of "ordered" triplets $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy the problem. That means for example, $(x,y,z)=(5,10,15)$ is a solution, then $(x,y,z)=(15,10,5)$ is also a different solution. The order matters. 
Now we can work out the solution in different ways. But I will only consider one way. Since $x,y,z$ are in A.P., we can have $x=a-d,y=a,z=a+d$, where $d$ is the common difference and $a$ the first term. This gives $(a-d)+(a)+(a+d)=3a=30,$ or $a=10$. This tells us that no matter what, the middle term always has to be $10$. Now, since $a-d=x>0, a-d>0\implies10-d>0\implies d<10$. Similarly, from$a+d=z>0$, we get that $d>-10$. So $d=9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9.$ 
If one knows counting, we can check that these are 19 distinct values of $d$ and hence, 19 different triplets $(x, y, z)$. People have been considering only positive $d$ and then doubling the number of triplets. That accounts for negative $d$ that they didn't consider, which works because the values of $d$ are symmetric about $0$. And adding the extra case of $ d=0$ in that method, you get the final answer of 19.

Comment: Thanks for such simple and elaborate expaination

Comment: Just asking how do you guys type in this mathematical font.

Comment: $a$ is not the first term of the AP

Comment: Yes a is not the first term of the AP . It's the middle term in his way of solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, a typo on my side! $a$ is the middle term.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x=a-d$, $y=a$ and $z=a+d$ be three natural numbers in Arithmetic Progression. Assume, without loss of generality that $x<y<z$ This clearly suggests that both $a,d$ $\in\mathbb{W}$

$\implies x+y+z=a-d+a+a+d=30$

$\implies a=10$

Hence $x=10-d,$ $y=10$ and $z=10+d$

Those numbers will represent an Arithmetic Progression when $d\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

So in total we get $10$ triplets. Since in the beginning we assumed $x<y<z$ we will now assume $z<y<x$ and so we'll now get another $10$ triplets. We got $20$ triplets on total but the case where $d=0$ yeilds same triplet irrespective of the fact that $z<y<x$ or $x<y<z$

So we have in total $19$ triplets

Comment: You got $11$ possible values of $d$, hence $22$ triplets, and hence $21$ after correcting the double counting for $d=0$. To get the answer $19$, you'd have to pretend that $0$ is not a natural number, so that $10$ is no longer a possible value of $d$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks

Comment: The total of solutions $(x,y,z)$ in natural integers of $x+y+z=30$ is equal to $$1+2+3+\cdots+28=406$$ If we want to have $(x,y,z)$ in AP we need $y=10$ so $x=10-h$ and $z=10+h$ where $h$ can take the values from $1$ to $9$ (zero in not a natural number!). Consequently there are just $9$ possibilities if we consider the reason $h$ as positive. If we assume also the case where $h$ is negative we have $18$ possibilities.